# Paper-dialog with iron-pages and inside each page paper-dialog-scrollable

Tags: polymer

Using Polymer 1 I'm trying to figure out a way to dinamically switch pages inside a paper-dialog and inside each page to have a paper-dialog-scrollable element.

Here's the short version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<paper-dialog with-backdrop>
    <iron-pages selected="0">
        <div>
             <paper-dialog-scrollable>
             Long content 1 goes in here...
             </paper-dialog-scrollable>
        </div>
        <div>
             <paper-dialog-scrollable>
             Long content 2 goes in here...
             </paper-dialog-scrollable>
        </div>
    </iron-pages>
</paper-dialog>
```

The issue is that the paper-dialog-scrollable, when the window is resized, goes over the paper-dialog edges and no scrollbars get shown.

I've looked a the code for paper-dialog-scrollable and it has a "dialogElement" property that is by default "this.parentNode". I've also tried to change that from the code with each page change but I cannot get it to work. Here's the "code":

```
this.querySelector('iron-pages').selectedItem.querySelector('paper-dialog-scrollable').dialogElement = this.querySelector('paper-dialog');
```

The last attempt I made was to trigger the refit and notifyResize on the dialog just under the above snippet of code, using the following:

```
this.querySelector('paper-dialog').notifyResize();
this.querySelector('paper-dialog').refit();
```

Maybe someone has ran into this issue and found a solution to this!?
Any hints or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to have the `iron-pages` element inside the `paper-dialog-scrollable` instead of the other way around?

Comment: Hi Neil, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. I would like each page to have a different "paper-toolbar" for instance. This is why I would like to have each page with its own "paper-dialog-scrollable".